# What does "forwarding all gas to the recipient" mean?

Tags: solidity, gas, openzeppelin

I am reading OpenZeppelin's `Escrow.sol` smart contract. The `withdraw` function's [comment](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/c1d6e39aab042a38a90f618c614a298522851f7b/contracts/utils/escrow/Escrow.sol#L47) says: "Withdraw accumulated balance for a payee, forwarding all gas to the recipient.". What does `forwarding all gas` here mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [withdraw](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/c1d6e39aab042a38a90f618c614a298522851f7b/contracts/utils/escrow/Escrow.sol#L58) function, it calls `payee.sendValue(payment);`. The `sendValue` function is declared in the [Address](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/c1d6e39aab042a38a90f618c614a298522851f7b/contracts/utils/Address.sol#L60) library. And as we can see, it sends the balance using the `.call` function.

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=address%20initial#members-of-address-types), the `.call` function forwards all the gas to the recipient. This is ideal in case a recipient is also a contract that wants to run some other logic and this way it does not run out of gas.

As you can also see from the documentation, the `.transfer` and `.send` function only forward 2300 gas, which is enough to receive ether, but not enough to do more complex operations while receiving the ether, like modifying the state of the recipient contract.

That's why it says that is forwarding all the gas to the recipient, because it's sending the eth using the `.call` function instead of the `.send` or `.transfer` functions.

The gas that is not used by the recipient is returned to the sender contract, and the gas that it does not use is then refunded to the original sender. This way, previous senders can continue doing more operations.

Documentation:

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=address%20initial#members-of-address-types

Address library:

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/c1d6e39aab042a38a90f618c614a298522851f7b/contracts/utils/Address.sol#L60